# Create + Serve (over HTTP) a .ZIP file, without writing to disk?

Tags: http, go, zip

I am wanting to serve a .ZIP file that is created on the fly, without having to write it to disk (I/O will slow down performance) and serve it to the client over HTTP.

Here is how I first attempted this:

```
func ZipServe(W http.ResponseWriter, R *http.Request) {

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
writer := zip.NewWriter(buf)

// for the sake of this demonstration, this is the data I will zip
data := ioutil.ReadFile("randomfile.jpg")

f, err := writer.Create("randomfile.jpg")
if err != nil { 
    fmt.Println(err)
}

_, err = f.Write(data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

io.Copy(W, buf)

err := writer.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

}
```

This is no good, as the .ZIP ends up being corrupt after downloading. I suppose the issue has to do with io.Copy; shall I be using a different method?

Comment: You're copying the zip writer before you close it.

Comment: @JimB what is preferred?, to `io.Copy(w, buf)` or to `w.Write(buf.Bytes())`

Comment: @nbari: Since we know that `buf` is a `bytes.Buffer` so the entire file is already in a slice, I'd prefer the second since we technically don't need the Copy call. In practice either is fine.

Comment: @Steven Smithson did you manage to get solution for this?

Answer (score 15):

I found interesting this and just for testing came up with this:

http://play.golang.org/p/JKAde2jbR3

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func zipHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    filename := "randomfile.jpg"
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := zip.NewWriter(buf)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f, err := writer.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = f.Write([]byte(data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s.zip\"", filename))
    //io.Copy(w, buf)
    w.Write(buf.Bytes())
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/zip", zipHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I just add some headers like the `Content-Type`  and `Content-Disposition`.

Also instead of using `io.Copy(w, buf)` I am writing directly `w.Write(buf.Bytes())` wondering if this is better? probably a more experienced user could clarify this.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly simpler method using [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy). It's probably not as performant as using a buffers for larger file sizes, but it works for me:

```golang
func handleZip(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Open("main.go")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    // write straight to the http.ResponseWriter
    zw := zip.NewWriter(w)
    cf, err := zw.Create(f.Name())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s.zip\"", f.Name()))


    // copy the file contents to the zip Writer
    _, err = io.Copy(cf, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // close the zip Writer to flush the contents to the ResponseWriter
    err = zw.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top rated answer should work, but will be high memory usage on large files. It's reading the whole file into memory. While it avoids writing to disk, it might have other performance issues on large files.

Good news is that the golang zip library is capable of streaming without loading the entire file into memory! Here's how to do it.

Two lower code options using a library (disclosure I'm the author):

1. You can use a dedicated micro service for this without writing it yourself (disclosure I'm the author): [ZipStreamer](https://github.com/scosman/zipstreamer)
2. If you want to incorporate this into your own service, you can use the same project as a library. Create your stream with `ZipStream.NewStream`, and pass it the http.ResponseWriter writer to the constructor. See `server.go/streamEntries` for an example which sets all the necessary HTTP headers. It takes care of everything to keep memory and CPU low.

If you want to write this from scratch, here's an example. The key is to use something like `io.Copy` which has a 32kb buffer built in and a buffered reader; that way you won't load the entire file into memory and it should scale to files of any size.

```
func zipHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    // You need to write the headers and status code before any bytes
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    // the filename which will be suggested in the save file dialog
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "attachment.zip"))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(w)

    for _, entry := range <<yourListOfFiles>> {
        header := &zip.FileHeader{
            Name:     entry.pathInNewZip,
            Method:   zip.Store, // deflate also works, but at a cost
            Modified: time.Now(),
        }
        entryWriter, err := zipWriter.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        fileReader := bufio.NewReader(entry.pathToFile)

        _, err = io.Copy(entryWriter, fileReader)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        zipWriter.Flush()
        flushingWriter, ok := z.destination.(http.Flusher)
        if ok {
            flushingWriter.Flush()
        }
    }

    return zipWriter.Close()
}
```